# "Bounties Earned" tab showing that I earned a 0 rep bounty from a bounty I placed

Tags: support, status-bydesign, bounties, profile-page

On my "[Bounties Earned](https://stackoverflow.com/users/172322/yahelc?tab=bounties#bpage_1-bsort_earned)" page, one of them is a bounty that I'm listed as earning 0 points on being awarded, "[Can I use Google Analytics to sort out the statistics of my iOS app?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4894803/172322)"

Except, I was the one who offered the bounty, so I couldn't have awarded it to myself, and certainly could not have been awarded 0 points.

[image]

(But, I did end up being the accepted answer; that could be a factor here, too).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You "earned" it because you had the highest-voted answer when it expired. But you got 0 points from it because you cannot award a bounty to yourself.

Comment: Ahhh. Thanks. That sort of makes sense.